Azure Function - Write into a table
I have a problem writing into a table of an Azure SQL database, I have followed the steps indicated into the documentation:

After the creation of the function app resource, I've created an azure function using the Http template and the "v1 Programming Model".
Language used: python 3.11
Runtime version: 4.34.1.1


I have an Azure SQL database in which I have created a table with the following command:
CREATE TABLE dbo.ToDo 
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    [order] INT NULL,
    [title] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [url] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [completed] BIT NOT NULL
);


In the networking tab of the database I've checked the option "Allow Azure services and resource to access this server".

Within the tab of the "environment variables" of the function app I have created the SqlConnectionString variable following the template in the documentation and replacing the SQL auth parameters accordingly.

I've set up the bindings in the function.json as:
{
    "authLevel": "function"
    "type": "httpTrigger",
    "direction": "in",
    "name": "req",
    "methods": [
        "post"
    ]
},
{
    "type": "http",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "$return"
},
{
    "name": "todoItems",
    "type": "sql",
    "direction": "out",
    "commandText": "dbo.ToDo",
    "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString"
}


The content of the init.py file is:


import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, todoItems: func.Out[func.SqlRow]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger and SQL output binding function processed a request.')

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        rows = func.SqlRowList(map(lambda r: func.SqlRow.from_dict(r), req_body))
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if req_body:
        todoItems.set(rows)
        return func.HttpResponse(
            todoItems.to_json(),
            status_code=201,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Error accessing request body",
            status_code=400
        )


When I try to test the function from the portal passing this JSON within the body:
{
    "order": 1,
    "title": "test",
    "url": "testUrl",
    "completed": 1
}



I get an error

500 Internal Server Error

Could someone help me to figure out why this error occurs?
I would expect the function to return the status 200 and the record inserted into the table.

Well you have to try to get a little more infomation about the error. 500 typically means there is some uncaught exception. But hard to say what it is. Could be an faulty connect string, could be a faulty query, .... Impossible to say from your little code ... Try to add some logging and more exception handling

First of "Allow Azure services and resource to access this server" does not include Azure Functions. Either you need to allow all traffic, inject functions and the DB into a VNET or add the egress IPs of the function to the database.
I would also recommend to add application insights or some more logging to your app

rows = func.SqlRowList(map(lambda r: func.SqlRow.from_dict(r), req_body))
looks for more than one elements provided in request_body.
For me
rows = func.SqlRow.from_dict(req_body)
solved the issue.
